# How to store all mp4 files names in an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, file

I want to move a file from another directory to the current directory. I have no problem with moving a file from current to another. But the other way around I get this error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "'Test''.mp4"

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Cant find file: "'Test''.mp4" -> ".\'Test''.mp4"

```
filesMove = os.listdir(os.curdir)
for file in filesMove:
    if '.mp4' in file:
        shutil.move(file, '/Users\caspe\OneDrive\Documents\Övrigt\Kodning\Youtube\Clips')
time.sleep(5)

twitchClipTitle=os.listdir(r"C:\Users\caspe\OneDrive\Documents\Övrigt\Kodning\Youtube\Clips")
print(twitchClipTitle)

filesClips = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\caspe\OneDrive\Documents\Övrigt\Kodning\Youtube\Clips")
for file in filesClips:
    shutil.move(file, os.curdir) #I get the error here
```

The purpose of this code is to save all the mp4 files' names in a list. Is there a better way?

Comment: `file` is just the name of the file. You need to give `.move()` the relative path to that file from the current directory, or the absolute path to the file, for it to be able to find the file. Giving it just the filename makes it look in the current directory for the file. [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: alright so it should be:     shutil.move(r"C:\Users\caspe\OneDrive\Documents\Övrigt\Kodning\Youtube\Clips\" + file, os.curdir) But i get a syntax error at Clips\

Comment: That's because raw strings can't end with a backslash.

Comment: But how should I get the directory for the file then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the directory in the call to `move` and use front slashes. Python will translate the front slashes based on os.

```
filesMove = os.listdir(os.curdir)
for file in filesMove:
    if '.mp4' in file:
        shutil.move(file, '/Users/caspe/OneDrive/Documents/Övrigt/Kodning/Youtube/Clips')
time.sleep(5)

twitchClipTitle=os.listdir(r"C:/Users/caspe/OneDrive/Documents/Övrigt/Kodning/Youtube/Clips")
print(twitchClipTitle)

fldr = r"C:/Users/caspe/OneDrive/Documents/Övrigt/Kodning/Youtube/Clips/"
filesClips = os.listdir(fldr)
for file in filesClips:
    shutil.move(fldr + file, os.curdir) #I get the error here
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thank you!